# Algorithm for integral of standard distribution

Tags: algorithms, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I need help in producing random data that follows standard distribution.
Since it is to be used in a computer application, I would prefer an algorithm before a table.

So, this is what I need.
The formula for normal distributions is as follows:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi }}}e^{{-(x-\mu)^2}/{2\sigma^2}}$$

I know this function has no primitive function that can be described analytically, so I am stuck with:

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$$

If I have a random value $n$ where $n \in [0,1]$, I would like to have an algorithm to make an approximate calculation on the value of $x$ when

$$F(x) = n$$

**Edit**

I am not asking for you to create this algorithm as I am sure it already exists. I just need help in pointing me towards it as I can't seem to find it no matter how much I search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two arch classical algorithms to simulate normal random variables are the [Box-Muller method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) and [acceptance-rejection samplings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling). A version of the latter is as follows:

1. Generate $u$, $v$ and $w$ independent uniform on $(0,1)$.
2. Set $x=-\log u$.
3. If $v^2\gt\exp(-(x-1)^2)$, go to 1 (*rejection*).
4. Else (*acceptance*), if $w\lt\frac12$, set $x=-x$.
5. Return $x$.

Comment: one of us completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: This is what I was searching for. I still don't know how it could elude my search attempt. Thanks both Did and robjohn for your answers

Comment: @nbubis It certainly appears so.

Comment: @ANisus You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for is the [Box-Muller Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform). An improved algorithm for generation is the [Marsaglia Polar Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method).  Both generate [normally distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) data from [uniformly distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) data.